# Django: Invalid block tag: 'wordList[key]', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'

Tags: django, templates, tags, block

I have a problem when I was using django template:

```
{% for key in wordList %}        
     <li><a href="#" data-weight={% wordList[key] %} >{{ key }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Django would say: Invalid block tag: 'wordList[key]', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Here the wordList is a dictionary, for example: {'Fish':19, 'Chips':5 }

How can I insert django block in the html sentence? I want them to be like:

```
    <li><a href="/fish" data-weight="60">Fish</a></li>
    <li><a href="/chips" data-weight="50">Chips</a></li>
```

How to do with the double quotation " " marks?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate directly over the key/value pairs:

```
{% for key, value in wordList.items %}
    <li><a href="#" data-weight="{{ value }}">{{ key }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

You can do dictionary-style lookups with dot syntax in a template, but only when you know the key rather than having it in an template variable.

Comment: Thanks! Can I do some calculations in template, like {% size = value*(20/maxnum) %}?

Comment: Very minimal calculations - mostly comparisons, but the `widthratio` built in can do some math that might be relevant to that example.  For more advanced stuff, you typically do the calculations in the view, add a model method to output it, or write a custom template tag.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/ for the full docs.